# Is "Hello/OK Boomers" disparaging?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, american-english, forms-of-address

Last year I read that [American Congressperson Ocasio Cortez aka AOC (OK Boomer) used the term](https://mashable.com/article/alexandria-ocasio-cortez-ok-boomer-bernie-sanders/) to bring to task some older members of US Congress who seemed to be ignoring the wishes and desires of the Millennial generation.

More recently, I read [an article by Eli Pariser entitled "Hello Boomer](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/03/13/opinions/boomers-boronavirus-millennials-pariser/index.html)", and for me it sounded a little condescending.

Admittedly he goes on to express concern for older adults, but it sounds as if  he believes those over the age of 60 are... well, helpless in basic web skills.

Does the "Millennial generation" consider this phrase to be disparaging, and do "Boomers" consider it to be condescending? I know I do.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105698/discussion-on-question-by-rattler-is-hello-ok-boomers-disparaging).

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of using the phrase *OK, boomer* is to convey the opinion that some view that the boomer in question has expressed is a manifestation of the prejudices that are typical of baby boomers, and is therefore not worthy of being taken seriously. The phrase dismisses whatever the boomer may have said as a manifestation of the irrationality that, the speaker assumes, comes naturally with being a boomer. The phrase is an argumentum ad hominem, which implies that there is no point in responding to the boomer’s views by a genuine argument, because no boomer would be able to understand it. Such a dismissal is bound to be offensive to the boomers, who may well believe that they have good, thought-out reasons for their views. Given that the purpose of the phrase is to dismiss somebody's views in this way, it is not clear how anybody could think that it is not offensive.

Of course, as with almost any other offensive term, there can be some special contexts in which the offensiveness is neutralised (for example, the term may be used among friends, in a manner that will be recognised as joking).

The word *boomer* can, of course, be used in all manner of other contexts, without being offensive. Now, if the use of the phrase *OK, boomer* becomes so widespread, that people start encountering it more often than the non-offensive uses of *boomer*, it is possible that its offensiveness will rub off on the word *boomer* itself, and that some people will start perceiving it as offensive in any context. That, however, hasn’t happened so far.

Comment: I'm not a boomer, but I still find many uses of "OK boomer" annoying if not strongly offensive. When the term first started to gain popularity I saw a lot of examples where it seemed the perfect response to something a boomer had said because it encapsulated why the boomer's statement was misguided and/or wrong. But now the majority of uses I see are just dismissing *anything* people of older generations say even when they're right and the younger person is wrong.

Comment: "which implies that there is no point in responding to the boomer’s views by a genuine argument, because no boomer would be able to understand it."  I disagree. I think it implies that the speaker is tired of defending themselves against irrational complaints only to have their arguments summarily dismissed. Hence, rather than try to argue, just  "agree" and move on.

Answer (score 1):

We can't know someone's intent without context, but my general understanding (as one on the older side of the case) is that it's usually meant to be mildly dismissive. How it's perceived is even less susceptible of analysis, since that depends on the hearer's state of mind which we cannot know.

If it were aimed at me personally, I wouldn't care how it's intended, if it reflects the opinion of someone whose opinion I don't value.

For all that, I don't think this is quite on-topic here since it is a question of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you reverse it you can clearly see it is condescending.

*OK, Boomer.
Now, children, lets not be condescending.*

The reply, "Now children" is clearly condescending.